# remove a list from nested list

Tags: python, list, nested

I am using Python, i have two nested lists the first

```
segments_list = [[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ['small', 'modest', 'little'], 16.218604324326577]]
```

the seconde

```
clusters_appearance_list = [[[0, 0], ['jack']], [[0, 4], ['study']], [[0, 4], ['small', 'modest', 'little']], [[0, 5], ['big', 'large']]]
```

i want to remove the list from `cluster_appearance_list` where there is `['small', 'modest', 'little']`

this is my code

```
for segment in segments_list:
for cluster in clusters_appearance_list:
    if segment[1] == cluster[1]:
        cluster.remove(cluster)
print(clusters_appearance_list)
```

i got this error

```
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Comment: `clusters_appearance_list.remove(cluster)`. But also you shouldn't modify a list while iterating through it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't try to modify a list while iterating through it. One way to do this nice and proper is with list comprehensions:

```py
segments_list = [[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ['small', 'modest', 'little'], 16.218604324326577]]

clusters_appearance_list = [[[0, 0], ['jack']], [[0, 4], ['study']], [[0, 4], ['small', 'modest', 'little']], [[0, 5], ['big', 'large']]]

clusters_appearance_list = [cluster for cluster in clusters_appearance_list for segment in segments_list if cluster[1] != segment[1]]

print(clusters_appearance_list)
```

Output:

```py
[[[0, 0], ['jack']], [[0, 4], ['study']], [[0, 5], ['big', 'large']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than removing the items from `cluster_appearance_list` you're attempting to remove the item from `cluster`

That is `cluster.remove(cluster)` should be changed to `clusters_appearance_list.remove(cluster)`

Your final code should look as follows:

```
segments_list = [[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ['small', 'modest', 'little'], 16.218604324326577]]
clusters_appearance_list = [[[0, 0], ['jack']], [[0, 4], ['study']], [[0, 4], ['small', 'modest', 'little']],
                            [[0, 5], ['big', 'large']]]

for segment in segments_list:
    for cluster in clusters_appearance_list:
        if segment[1] == cluster[1]:
            clusters_appearance_list.remove(cluster)
print(clusters_appearance_list)
```